# Hide Slide-Over on toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'd like this slide-over to be completely hidden when toggled off (resize browser window, it still shows).[Jquery-Slide-Over](https://github.com/jme783/slide-). How do I do this?

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 1024px) {
  .slide-over {
    width: 80%;
    right: -80%;
  }
  .slide-over.left {
    right: auto;
    left: -80%;
  }
  .close-x {
    top: 12px;
    right: 20px;
  }
  .slide-over .slideover-content {
    padding: 2em 4em 1em;
  }
}
```

```js
// Close the slideout when clicking X or outside panel
$('*[data-slideover="close"]').click(function() {
  var currentContent = $('.slide-over div.slideover-content');
  closeSlider();
});

function closeSlider() {
  $('.overlay').fadeOut(settings.animationSpeed);
  // Remove the content inside the panel
  panel.animate({
    right: (settings.orientation == 'right' ? -panelWidth : "auto"),
    left: (settings.orientation == 'left' ? -panelWidth : "auto")
  }, settings.animationSpeed, function() {
    $("body").css("overflow", "auto");
    if ($.isFunction(settings.onClose)) {
      settings.onClose.call(this);
    }
  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: could you please add some sample code

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I've added the close function and the width % onclose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 right: (settings.orientation == 'right' ? -(panelWidth*2) : "auto"),
 left: (settings.orientation == 'left' ? -(panelWidth*2) : "auto")
```

Figured it out